# Angular UI Router HTML5 Mode Typing in Address Bar

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

After some experimenting with ui-router's html5 mode, the behavior I'm seeing is when a path is typed into the address bar, the entire page refreshes with the expected state.  Even if I don't change the path, even pressing 'enter' with the address bar having focus causes a complete page refresh/render.

Without html5 mode, after typing a path after the # symbol, the expected state is activated, but without refreshing and rendering the entire page.

Is this the intended behavior of html5 mode, to refresh and render the entire page when a user types a path into the address bar?

Comment: That's how browsers work.

Comment: So html5 mode has the benefit of removing the hash character from the URL but at the cost of losing spa functionality when the user manually enters a URL?  Non html5 mode seems like a cleaner solution, I mean the whole point of an spa is to not refresh the entire page on navigation.

Comment: Browser has no way to know it's an SPA when you type something in address bar and use browser controls. Issue is not a big deal ... how often do users do this vs internal app navigation which uses pushstate and doesn't reload

Comment: It sort of does know its and SPA if you use non-html5 mode and URL hashes.  As for how often users do this vs internal app navigation, JS developers need to stop pretending that doesn't happen.  It happens all the time with applications targeted towards more savvy users.  Think of an app like github or gitlab, its way easier to type /project-name/issues/45 than to navigate through to find it.